# Adding unique buttons dynmaically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This is what I have right now:

[image]

When I click Add a Class, I want another button to appear directly above the 'Add a Class' Button. This newly created button, when clicked on, will switch to an activity that shows all the assignments for that class(new button). I think I have an idea how to do this, but only in its most basic form.

I guess there's really 3 things I'm unsure about:

1) How to add a button at a specific location within an xml file through java?

2) How do I add buttons with unique identifiers?

3) How do I click on the newly created buttons so that a new activity opens which only shows the assignments for that button?

This is how my xml layout currently looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#7BEDFC" >

<ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLlayoutBottomButtons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="Classes"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/rightarrow"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text=" Math" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Add a Class" />                               
    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the button the the linearLayout I guess (id mLlayoutBottomButtons). In your activity you do this:

```
LinearLayout buttonsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLlayoutBottomButtons);
```

You will dynamically create buttons, you **can** give it an id (button.setId(int id)), but it is not necessary. Just create and add it like this

```
Button newButton = new Button(this);
newButton.setText("New button");
buttonsLayout.addView(newButton, parentView.getChildCount() - 2); //see Edit at end of post
```

Now we created the button and added it to the layout. As last step you just set an OnClickListener to this button. Inside the onClick-method you can start the activity with an intent and add Extras in order to determine which assignment should be shown in the next Acitivty.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("assignmentType", "theNewButtonsAssignments");
startActivity(intent);
```

in the new Activity call getIntent().getStringExtra("assignmentType") to retrieve which assignment should be shown.

Edit:
You can use addView(View child, int index) for inserting it in a certain position inside the linearLayout.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful! One thing I'm unsure about though is the putExtra. Say I have buttonA in activity A and an activityB with buttonB. So when I click buttonA that brings me to ActivtyB, then when I click buttonB that adds buttonC on the current activity(ActivtyB).So in anytime when I go back to activtyA then click buttonA to go back to ActivtyB it will show me buttonC,buttonB and any other button created when I clicked buttonB.But if I navigate to ActivityB using another button from activtyA it will have a whole new set of buttons.ButtonB may be the same but the rest not.

Comment: You should review the purpose of Activity. An Activity doesn't have a state that you can change and its saved for next time. When you navigate back to ActivityA, it is possible that Activity B is completely destroyed and created newly when coming again. If you need to save a state, I suggest to do this in an independent class. If you want to save it permanently you can use SharedPreference or the Filesystem/Database.

Comment: I read something about making ActivityB have its view backed by a data model, could you maybe elaborate on this approach?

Comment: This is about architecture of your Application in general. You can skim some Wikipedia articles about Multitier architecture and Model-View-Controller. You don't have to try to apply them and understand them deeply, but you will understand what is meant with "data model". It means for you: seperate Assignment-objects from the Activity and store their state (like isActivated) seperated from the Activity. The Activity then just reads out the states (actived = button is there) and shows it in UI.